# How to manage screen to screen events with time spent by each user using Firebase Analytics

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase Analytics in my Android app.
I have done all the basic setup as per the Firebase documentation.
I am also able to log the data in the Firebase console. but I want some specific events to be logged in the console.

I want to log info like How much time will take for the user to go from say Login to the Main screen
and then the Main screen to some other screen.

And that also want to track by each user.

How do I achieve this and where can I find it in the Firebase console?

I have read about funnels. Can it be achieved by Firebase funnels and how?

Thank you.